# Function being called infinite times when used in render function using react

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a function that needs to be called when Save button is clicked. When function is being called with parenthesis, it gets called infinite times.

```
<ChildForm onSave={onClickRefresh()}  />
```

The onClickRefresh function is defined in the child component and is called using ref.

```
const onClickRefresh = async() => {
        if(activeListPageRef.current) {
            aPageRef.current.refreshEntirePage(updatedData);
        }
    }
```

In order to fix this issue, I tried to call the function without parenthesis, but it doesn't work. I don't understand why is it being called multiple times even when Save button is not clicked.

Comment: `onClickRefresh()` calls the function so every render the function is called.

Comment: You are not passing the function, you are calling it. `onSave={onClickRefresh}` this passes the function to the child. There is not enough info to see if you have different sideeffects that cause your component to rerender. Try: https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Comment: With the parenthesis you are immediately invoking the function, regardless of how `ChildForm` is consuming the `onSave` prop. If you've fixed the immediate invoking issue and the callback isn't called then you've an issue in `ChildForm` component. Please update your question to include all relevant code. We should see what `ChildForm` is doing with its props. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function automatically, try this:

```
<ChildForm onSave={()=>onClickRefresh()}  />

<ChildForm onSave={onClickRefresh}  />
```

Comment: Neither of the solution work. Its not even calling the function

Comment: Can you upload the code to sandbox vs jsfiddle?